# z-index not working for overlapping elements

Tags: html, css

I have a scrollable box with text in it, which expands upon hovering over it, with a small amount of text also above it. When I hover over the scrollable text box, It expands, also overlapping the small bit of text above it. I have tried this with z-index, but just cannot get the scrollable text box to overlap.

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wvpsrk) is a StackBlitz of my issue (should be fairly explanatory).

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Does adding `background-color:white;` to `.eula-text` class do the trick?

Comment: Isn't your `.eula-text` element simply missing a background colour? The `z-index` seems to work for me.

Comment: Please include a [mcve] in your question -- linking to an off-site code sandbox is insufficient per Stack Overflow's guidelines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `background-color: white` to your `.eula-text` class to make the background of your text non-transparent.